# innerHTML doesn't work when used with Plus/Min button

Tags: javascript

In my code below I want to console log and innerHTML the value of (var inputField) when it is Incremented and decremented by + and - buttons but my code doesn't work. Can any one help me solve this issue?

```js
const minusButton = document.getElementById('minus');
const plusButton = document.getElementById('plus');
var inputField = document.getElementById('input');

minusButton.addEventListener('click', event => {
  const currentValue = Number(inputField.value);
  inputField.value = currentValue - 1;
});

plusButton.addEventListener('click', event => {
  const currentValue = Number(inputField.value);
  inputField.value = currentValue + 1;
});

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = inputField.value;
  console.log(inputField.value);
}
```

```html
<button id="minus">−</button>
<input type="number" value="" id="input" onchange="myFunction()" />
<button id="plus">+</button>

<p id="a"></p>
```

Comment: Programatically changing the input value does not trigger a _change_ event

Comment: I'd shame you for using innerHTML in the first place. That's the real problem here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set the value of an input element through code it doesn't call the `onchange` function. I'm not sure if this is all browsers or only some, but it seems like all. If you want to call the change event, call the function `myFunction` inside your button click functions. Or call the input's `change` function.

Either of the following works:

```
 minusButton.addEventListener('click', event => {
        const currentValue = Number(inputField.value);
        inputField.value = currentValue - 1;
        myFunction();
    });
```

Or

```
 minusButton.addEventListener('click', event => {
        const currentValue = Number(inputField.value);
        inputField.value = currentValue - 1;
        inputField.onchange();
    });
```